# Tag domain object as archived (write protect)

Tags: java, html, model-view-controller, design-patterns, grails

I'm having a simple hierarchy of domain objects. All knowing its childs and its only parent. There are no cycles.

I let my domain classes implement the interface

```
interface IArchivable {
   boolean isArchived()
}
```

Where child objects redirect this call to the parent object. The root object will have a (database) property which will be altered at any time.

Using *Groovy/Grails* (or for the ease of generality *model-view-controller*) :

- Whats the best practice to writeprotect this whole hierarchy? (Intercept controllers update method via *Groovys MetaProgramming* or *AOP*?)
- How do I easily write protect the html pages inputs, selects, ....?
- Assuming my model is more complex: A child has several parents, there are cycles. How could I implement this functionality then?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [grails domains events](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping). You can intercept the loading of your domains with the onLoad (or at time of updating, depend on your businness) event and make them read-only calling the grails [discard method](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html)